# What is the scope of an inner class Singleton in Java?

Tags: java, singleton, inner-classes

What is the scope of an inner class Singleton in Java?
I want a class with a Singleton-like class inside,
but every instance of the outer class should have its own instance of the inner class. (I know its not a good style of code, but I need to pack everything in one class for this setup.)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then it's not a Singleton.  That's not a bad idea.  No good reason for Singletons.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, stemming from a bad design. Maybe you step back for a second and try to find other ways around the **real** problem you are trying to solve. And lets be precise: this is **not** about bad code **style**, it is about bad **design**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare the inner class as private and create an instance every time you create the outer class you will have a single instance of the inner class per every instance of the outer class.

This is not the singleton pattern.

Something like that.

```
public class MyOuter {
    private MyOuter.MyInner inner;

    public MyOuter() {
        inner = new MyOuter.MyInner();
    }

    ...

    private static class MyInner {
        ....
    }
}
```